# processing confusing output of converted yolov8 model from .pt to .onnx

Tags: onnx, yolov8, onnxruntime

I have converted a .pt Yolov8 model that I transfer trained on a custom data set to an onnx file because I am attempting to deploy on an edge device that cannot build ultralytics versions that can load yolov8 models.

The converted onnx model does load and it does run predictions, but I can't quite work out how to process the output data! I am drawing boxes in completely wrong places.

I simplified it to two test scripts to inspect the outputs from processing the same image.

Any help greatly appreciated, if I can solve this it will save me a world of hurt.

.pt inspect output:

```
results: [ultralytics.engine.results.Results object with attributes:

boxes: ultralytics.engine.results.Boxes object
keypoints: None
masks: None
names: {0: 'trolley'}
orig_img: array([[[142, 144, 158],
        [173, 175, 188],
        [192, 194, 207],
        ...,
        [ 45,  53,  72],
        [ 44,  52,  71],
        [ 43,  51,  70]],

       [[138, 140, 153],
        [142, 144, 157],
        [145, 146, 159],
        ...,
        [ 45,  53,  72],
        [ 45,  53,  72],
        [ 45,  53,  72]],

       [[136, 137, 150],
        [161, 163, 176],
        [138, 140, 152],
        ...,
        [ 44,  52,  71],
        [ 46,  54,  73],
        [ 48,  56,  75]],

       ...,

       [[ 75,  81,  97],
        [ 77,  83,  99],
        [ 74,  80,  96],
        ...,
        [ 65,  67,  79],
        [ 65,  67,  79],
        [ 65,  67,  79]],

       [[ 77,  83,  99],
        [ 79,  85, 101],
        [ 76,  82,  98],
        ...,
        [ 64,  66,  78],
        [ 64,  66,  78],
        [ 64,  66,  78]],

       [[ 77,  83,  99],
        [ 80,  85, 101],
        [ 76,  82,  98],
        ...,
        [ 63,  65,  77],
        [ 63,  65,  77],
        [ 63,  65,  77]]], dtype=uint8)
orig_shape: (640, 640)
path: 'image0.jpg'
probs: None
save_dir: None
speed: {'preprocess': 0.0, 'inference': 81.86841011047363, 'postprocess': 48.83885383605957}]
0: 640x640 1 trolley, 81.9ms
Speed: 0.0ms preprocess, 81.9ms inference, 48.8ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

.onnx inspection output:

```
Number of output tensors: 1
Output predictions: [array([[[6.74059772e+00, 1.68045845e+01, 2.33795547e+01, ...,
         5.81766541e+02, 5.95164062e+02, 6.02357910e+02],
        [1.48594885e+01, 1.79399471e+01, 1.95681229e+01, ...,
         6.07668945e+02, 6.05005066e+02, 5.90472534e+02],
        [1.38631535e+01, 3.30112076e+01, 4.58652878e+01, ...,
         1.03839111e+02, 8.46026001e+01, 8.07698364e+01],
        [2.82973385e+01, 3.45392494e+01, 3.80951614e+01, ...,
         6.51624146e+01, 6.59660645e+01, 9.91400146e+01],
        [1.19209290e-07, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
         5.96046448e-08, 1.75833702e-06, 1.34110451e-06]]], dtype=float32)]
Output tensor shape: (1, 5, 8400)
Sample output values (first 10):
[ 6.7405977 16.804585  23.379555  25.867968  34.81388   40.286224
 45.366837  55.982033  70.706924  76.8924   ]
Number of detections per image: 8400
Sample detection values (first set of 5 values):
[6.74059772e+00 1.48594885e+01 1.38631535e+01 2.82973385e+01
 1.19209290e-07]
Slot 1: Min value: 2.1957478523254395, Max value: 636.6444702148438, Mean value: 318.2766418457031
Slot 2: Min value: 4.1632208824157715, Max value: 636.5177001953125, Mean value: 321.9232177734375
Slot 3: Min value: 5.034980773925781, Max value: 206.54994201660156, Mean value: 60.202857971191406
Slot 4: Min value: 6.93548583984375, Max value: 306.9089660644531, Mean value: 90.83543395996094
Slot 5: Min value: 0.0, Max value: 0.8410309553146362, Mean value: 0.0009538077283650637

Inspecting patterns in the first 10 detections for each slot:
Slot 1 first 10 values: [ 6.7405977 16.804585  23.379555  25.867968  34.81388   40.286224
 45.366837  55.982033  70.706924  76.8924   ]
Slot 2 first 10 values: [14.8594885 17.939947  19.568123  18.928112  12.157583   9.730759
  9.018981  11.631983   9.608661   7.939432 ]
Slot 3 first 10 values: [13.863153 33.011208 45.865288 47.089123 36.74875  32.579952 29.31453
 29.247162 27.974869 25.54161 ]
Slot 4 first 10 values: [28.297338 34.53925  38.09516  36.430298 23.29528  18.743835 17.69494
 23.052486 18.969786 15.53459 ]
Slot 5 first 10 values: [1.1920929e-07 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00
 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
Slots possibly containing confidence scores (0-100 range): [4]
```

.pt inspect script:

```
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2


DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

model_path = 'Trolley_Detect-02.pt'
image_path = '13.jpg'
model = YOLO(model_path)
model.to(DEVICE)


def preprocess_image(image, width, height):
    resized_frame = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))
    resized_frame = cv2.cvtColor(resized_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(resized_frame).unsqueeze(0).permute(0, 3, 1, 2).float().div(255.0).to(DEVICE)
    return img_tensor


frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
img_tensor = preprocess_image(frame, 640, 640)

with torch.no_grad():
    results = model(img_tensor)

print(f'results: {results}')
```

.onnx inspect script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime as ort
from PIL import Image

THRESHOLD = 0.5
NMS_THRESHOLD = 0.5
CLASSES = ["trolley"]

def preprocess_image(image_path, input_size=(640, 640)):
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize(input_size)
    image_np = np.array(image).astype(np.float32)
    image_np = np.transpose(image_np, (2, 0, 1))
    image_np /= 255.0
    image_np = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
    return image_np

def infer(model_path, input_tensor):
    session = ort.InferenceSession(model_path)
    input_name = session.get_inputs()[0].name
    predictions = session.run(None, {input_name: input_tensor})
    return predictions

def inspect_output_tensor(predictions):
    print(f"Number of output tensors: {len(predictions)}")
    print(f"Output predictions: {predictions}")
    # Assuming there's only one output
    output_tensor = predictions[0]
    print(f"Output tensor shape: {output_tensor.shape}")

    # Print the first 10 values in the output tensor for inspection
    print("Sample output values (first 10):")
    print(output_tensor.flatten()[:10])

    # Assuming the output tensor shape is (1, 5, N), where N is the number of detections
    num_detections = output_tensor.shape[2]
    print(f"Number of detections per image: {num_detections}")

    # Sample the first detection set (first set of 5 values) to inspect
    sample_detection = output_tensor[0, :, 0]
    print("Sample detection values (first set of 5 values):")
    print(sample_detection)

    # Inspect the range of values in each of the 5 slots across all detections
    for i in range(5):
        slot_values = output_tensor[0, i, :]
        print(
            f"Slot {i + 1}: Min value: {slot_values.min()}, Max value: {slot_values.max()}, Mean value: {slot_values.mean()}")

    print("\nInspecting patterns in the first 10 detections for each slot:")
    for i in range(5):
        slot_values_first_10 = output_tensor[0, i, :10]
        print(f"Slot {i + 1} first 10 values: {slot_values_first_10}")

    # If confidence scores are a range from 0 to 100 as suspected,
    # identify which slot(s) might contain these values
    possible_confidence_slots = [i for i in range(5) if
                                 (output_tensor[0, i, :].min() >= 0 and output_tensor[0, i, :].max() <= 100)]
    print(f"Slots possibly containing confidence scores (0-100 range): {possible_confidence_slots}")


image_path = "13.jpg"
input_tensor = preprocess_image(image_path)

model_path = "opset13/Trolley_Detect-02.onnx"
predictions = infer(model_path, input_tensor)

inspect_output_tensor(predictions)
```

conversion script:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO('Trolley_Detect-02.pt')  # load a custom trained model

# Export the model
model.export(format='onnx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the onnx model just has one output i.e. "output:0" when you try to visualize using netron.app, it is a concatenated output containing an array. I had the same problem with my model. The only solution to this was to include the nms inside the model, because if you can see the ultrlytics repository, they have nms implemented outside the model, in predictor.py file, that's why you are able to get the prediction values. But, when you run it on your own script rather then ultralytics, it doesn't have any nms implemented.

you can do 2 things:-
-- write the nms logic in your script but again you have to understand the output array from the model or else
-- add nms inside your model, this will directly give you the values as : num_detection, bounding_boxes, classes, conf_score in the form of seperate array values.

so here's an article that can help you solve your problem:-

https://stephencowchau.medium.com/stitching-non-max-suppression-nms-to-yolov8n-on-exported-onnx-model-1c625021b22

refer it to add nms to your model.
All the best, have fun...